# ASP.NET application takes long to resolve the default file for a folder

Tags: asp.net

Whenever I navigate to http://Myapp/Sales, or any other web folder without including the page it always takes 110.69s to resolve the page.
If I indicate the default page, http://Myapp/Sales/default.aspx it responds inmediately.

Is that something I missed on web.config?

Comment: If it happens on every server for this particular app, you have an issue in the app. If it happens only on one particular server, you have an issue on the server. In any case, we need more details.

Comment: Sure, just tell me what things would help you. I experienced this from time to time on the production server. Now that I wanted to use friendly URLs I got it on development. On production only uses generic URL when reconnecting a user. Hence why I didn't notice.